# Is it ok to use a function to output the text domain name in a wordpress theme

Tags: functions, theme-development, translation, textdomain

I am working on a theme and I want to make it available for translating. I have not been including a text domain on translated text because I don't know what the text domain is going to be yet. I figured, until I can come up with a name for my theme I should just use a function to output my text domain name instead of hard coding it on translated text.

EXAMPLE:

This is the traditional way of adding a text domain:

```
echo _e('Hello', 'my-theme-name');
```

my approach is like this:

```
function text_domain() {
   define('TEXT_DOMAIN', 'my-theme-name', true );
   echo TEXT_DOMAIN;
}
```

and using like this:

```
 echo _e('Hello', text_domian());
```

...and when I do come up with a name for my theme I can just update it in one place instead a bunch of times in every file.

THE QUESTION IS: Is this an ok way to do it and will I encounter problems getting my theme approved by the WordPress theme review team?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, this is not okay. NO NO NO. Here's [my favourite Otto quote](http://ottopress.com/2012/internationalization-youre-probably-doing-it-wrong/):

> Inside all translation functions, no PHP variables are allowed in the
>   strings, for any reason, ever.

Otto explains this in more detail, but the simple way to say **it is that translation calls are parsed, not executed** . So your variable  (let alone your function) may not be evaluated and the text-domain breaks.

So, you're better off using a unique name like `wpse241589` for your textdomain temporarily and do a search and replace once you have a better name.

Comment: The article you referenced answered my question and more, I greatly appreciate you taking the time to answer this question.

Comment: Touting my own, debatable take on textdomain: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/227148/localization-textdomain-is-slow-and-chaotic

Comment: Very instructive answer and link