# wordpress plugin translation not working

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, wp-admin, hooks, translation

I have no idea what is wrong here. First I would like to share probably all required info.

Plugin tree:

```
$ tree
.
├── classes
│   ├── database
│   │   ├── plugin-auth.php
│   │   ├── plugin-user.php
│   │   └── wp-user-x.php
│   ├── main
│   │   └── plugin.php
│   └── woocommerce
│       └── plugin-order.php
├── config.php
├── plugin.php
├── languages
│   ├── plugin-shop-en_US.mo
│   ├── plugin-shop-en_US.po
│   ├── plugin-shop-pl_PL.mo
│   └── plugin-shop-pl_PL.po
└── templates
    └── register.php
```

`plugin.php` contains Text Domain: `plugin-shop`

`.po` and `.mo` files were generated with Poedit

plugin contains similar code which is executed as first:

```
class Plugin
{
    const TEXT_DOMAIN = 'plugin-shop';

    public function initHooks()
    {
        add_action('plugins_loaded', array($this, 'load_textdomain'));
    }

    public function load_textdomain() {
        load_plugin_textdomain( self::TEXT_DOMAIN, false, basename( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages' ); 
    }
    ...
}
```

`classses/woocommerce/plugin-order.php` contains by example

```
function order_status_completed()
{
     wp_mail( $to, __('Something bought', $this->_textdomain ), $body, $headers );
}
```

where 'Something bought' were successfully indexed by Poedit

Problem happens when I'm trying to send mail to user on such an action.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', array($this, 'order_status_completed'), 10, 1 );
```

mail is sent but with english text.

1. Locale for WordPress are set to pl_PL - tested by sending in mail
   subject `locale()` result. Why is it sending original text?
2. By the way. I want to send mail with text basing on user locale received by `get_user_locale()` method. How to deal with it?

Comment: Your second question should be a separate one.

Answer (score 1):

This problem looks a bit too complicated and localized to come up with a definitive answer, but it looks like an execution order issue. Here are some suggestions what you could check:

1. You are using a variable in your translation function. [Do not do this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/241589/is-it-ok-to-use-a-function-to-output-the-text-domain-name-in-a-wordpress-theme/241597#241597).
2. I'm not sure where that Woocommerce-action is executed, but it might be executed [before WP gets to](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) the `load_textdomain` hook. Not very likely, but not impossible either if it tries to send the mail immediately after the plugin is loaded.
3. Your `add_action` uses the default priority. Higher or lower might help.
4. Check the global `$wp_filter` variable to see of some plugin is messing with the locales.

Comment: The problem were wrong languages path. **basename( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages' )** 
My bad - Plugin class is defined in main/plugin.php file so language path  were wp-content/plugins/main/languages/plugin-shop-pl_PL.po which is bad. Thanks for your suggestions. Thanks to this i've found Query Monitor tool where is Languages section which displayed me bad path.