# Language string not detecting used within the function

Tags: localization, language

I am using Mpdf lib to generate PDF for the plugin I am developing. The PDF has much more tabular data that require localization.

For that, I have created a function for `TH` and `TD` as below.

```
function gs_pdf_th(string $text, $style = FALSE, string $class = 'header')
{
    return '<th class="' . $class . '" ' . $style . '>' . __($text, 'group-shop') . '</th>';
}
```

This function's problem is `PO` is not detecting the `$text` string for localization. All other text from the file where I used this function has been detected, but this one.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/241589/is-it-ok-to-use-a-function-to-output-the-text-domain-name-in-a-wordpress-theme/241597#241597

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t use variables in translation functions. From the [internationalisation documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/handbook/internationalization/internationalization-guidelines/#variables):

> The following example tells you what not to do
>
> ```
> // This is incorrect do not use.
> _e( "Your city is $city.", 'my-theme' );
> ```
>
> The strings for translation are extracted from the source without executing the PHP associated with it. For example: The variable `$city` may be Vancouver, so your string will read `"Your city is Vancouver"` when the template is run but gettext won’t know what is inside the PHP variable in advance.

You need to put the value in the translation function when initially  defining it.

Comment: Oh, I see... I didn't seem aware that the function won't detect the string passed using a variable. Good to know. Thanks. I can handle it now.